# Proper explanation for NodeJS/Typescript Export / Import?

Tags: node.js, import, typescript, tslint

I am seeking information on how exports and imports work in NodeJS using TypeScript.

My setup is:

- NodeJS
- Everything in Typescript
- TSLint
- Typings

I am messing about with exports/imports instead of doing some proper coding, it's driving me nuts, and cannot find any proper explanation of how it works.

**Import**

What do the following mean?

```
var module = require ("module");

import module = require("module");

import module from "module";

import {something} from "module";

import * as module from "module";
```

**Export**

What do the following mean?

```
export = something;

export default something;

export interface|class something;
```

**Questions**

- How do properly export/import a class without initiating it
- How do properly export/import a class with it being initiated (construct did run)
- How do I properly export/import a class and interface
- How do I properly export/import class and multiple interfaces
- When to use modules declarations, what are they good for and why is tslint throwing errors at me if I try to use them.

I cannot seem to find proper way of doing exports vs. imports so my IDE is not covered in red and throwing hundreds of errors at me.

**General Questions**

- Is there even a way to not get errors using Nodejs/TypeScript/tslint?
- TSLint is screaming at me for almost anything I type... it is **extremely frustrating** since there is no explanation to most of the errors. Is it even worth using it?

List of questions goes on and on, but I'm sure once some of the above is answered, I can pick up on the rest.

Comment: Yep, dividing your TypeScript code into multiple files for separation concerns is currently on par with _blashphemy_. You either need to reference source files for correct ordering when using internal namespaces (!), or you need to constrain your compiled code to a module loading system (!!) syntax, so that your compiled code can run (!!!). I'm hoping this will resolve in the _very_ near future, because at the moment TypeScript is far from being a decent choice for "application-grade Javascript development" (without a lengthy and painful project configuration, that is).

Comment: @JohnWhite having modules is a good thing hence their introduction to Javascript (ES6/2015). Multiple named exports can be regrouped in a single TS file.  The use of `namespace`s in Typescript should be avoided as much as possible

Comment: @BrunoGrieder Indeed they are, but not when you are (should be) able to seamlessly compile a project into an executable resource (which is Javascript in this case). But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 19):

Agreed, import/export syntax is confusing for at least two reasons:

- the commonjs syntax: `var module = require ("module");` works but that is commonjs -> no typings
- it changed: the syntax `import x = require('y'`) is now deprecated in TS

**TL;DR;**: Use the 'es6 style' syntax introduced in TS 1.5

The 'best' resource on import/export in TS I know is [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#es6-modules)

Overall I recommend reading this [excellent handbook](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/) which will provide answers to most of your questions

### To import

**From a default export**

`Something` was exported as a default (single) export ie `export default Something` in ts/es6

Use

```
import Something from "module"
```

You can actually import a default export with a different name. `import SomethingElse from 'module'` will also work

**From named exports**

`Something` was exported as a named export in "module"  using `export {Something}` or `export class|interface Something{}` in ts/es6

You want to import only that, use

```
import {Something} from "module"
```

You want to import everything that is exported from "module" under the namespace `mod`

```
import * as mod from "module
```

Then use `const c:mod.Something = whatever`

### To export

See `import`s above

The form `export = something` is deprecated in favor of the new ES6 style syntax. It is mostly found in definition files to express the fact that a js library exports a single function/object e.g. `module.exports=something`.

### What you should try using

Use ES6 style syntax and avoid `default` exports: they have the advantage that they can be imported using a different name but

- a default import cannot be re-exported, which may be problematic if you are writing a library
- they will confuse a lot of IDEs (not to mention yourself) when refactoring
- a named export can actually be locally renamed when imported i.e. `import {Something as SomethingElse} from "module"`

Concretely, export whatever needs to be exported and import it specifically

In `api.ts`

```
export interface MyInterface {
}

export class MyClass {
}
```

In `main.ts`

```
 import {MyInterface, MyClass} from './api'
```

## Linting

There are a lot of good IDEs out there that provide excellent linting: VSCode, Atom Typescript and Webstorm to name a popular few, the first two being free and the third one even manages the imports for you.

Comment: Would just like to add that `import foo from require('foo')` is an important pattern as well as some modules haven't been updated for es6. That CommonJS fallback will help. :)

Comment: I've found that https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242#issue-60179656 is a very useful summary of things as well.

I also agree with avoiding `export default` for now. It can increase complexity in a lot of subtle ways and just isn't worth the convenience it provides.