# Cannot find name of module in same directory

Tags: typescript

The code compiles and runs, but I'm getting errors with the type checking which blows up with a lot of files and variables. Here's an example.

**Test1.ts**

```
import Test2 = require('./Test2');

class Test1 {
    test2: Test2;
    constructor() {
        this.test2 = new Test2();
    }
}

console.log(new Test1());
```

**Test2.ts**

```
export = class Test2 {
    prop: number;
    constructor() {
        this.prop = 5;
    }
}
```

Running `tsc --module commonjs Test1.ts` gives me this error:

```
Test1.ts(4,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Test2'.
```

And running the code outputs:

```
Test1 { test2: Test2 { prop: 5 } }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use export= / import= syntax. Its better to do it like this:

Test1.ts

```
import {Test2} from './Test2';

class Test1 
{
    test2: Test2;
    constructor() {
        this.test2 = new Test2();
    }
}

console.log(new Test1());
```

Test2.ts

```
export class Test2 
{
    prop: number;
    constructor() 
    {
        this.prop = 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting....this works. Why is this better? I'm happy this works but I'm curious as to why the other one _didn't_.

Comment: A downside I've discovered with this is that it makes requiring the compiled files from a vanilla javascript disgusting since you have to go through the namespace like `var Test1 = require('./Test1').Test1`

Comment: To fix your code by sticking to the original wy I would set export like this: export = Test2;
Have a look at a some good explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455720/proper-explanation-for-nodejs-typescript-export-import

Comment: That link was super helpful! Thanks a bunch! :)