# What is the difference between import crypto from 'crypto' vs just using crypto in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use crypto to get a UUID in my new Node project. I found a solution to use crypto for that and I found out that crypto itself is a declared variable already without importing it. So both are possible:

```
import crypto from 'crypto'
const mything = crypto
```

and also without the import just:

```
const mything = crypto
```

Is there a difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper explanation for NodeJS/Typescript Export / Import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455720/proper-explanation-for-nodejs-typescript-export-import)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't import it, it doesn't exist (at least as of Node.js v17.1.0), so without the `import` it's an error. *(But see below.)* There is no `crypto` listed in [Node's documentation of its globals](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html), and a quick test shows that `crypto` is indeed not defined unless you import it.

If you do `node example.js` with this file, for instance, you get `undefined`:

```
console.log(typeof crypto);
```

*(But again, see below.)*

Note that this is different from the browser environment. In the browser environment, [`crypto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto) is a predefined global.

This **may** change on the Node.js side, as the environment continues to evolve toward full compatibility with web APIs. At some point, it's possible `crypto` will get added to Node.js's predefined globals. But it isn't (yet). But if it does change, it will be the web crypto API, not the one from the `crypto` module.

[ruohola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9835872/ruohola) points out that if you use the REPL, `crypto` **is** predefined:

```
node
Type ".help" for more information.
> typeof crypto
'object'
> crypto === require("crypto")
true
```

As you can see, the object available via the `crypto` global available in the REPL is the same as the module you get from `require("crypto")`.

Comment: `$ node
Welcome to Node.js v14.17.6.
Type ".help" for more information.
> crypto`
**Does** work for me, no errors.

Comment: @ruohola - That's not the same environment as code you run via `node somefile.js`. If you try it there, it **doesn't** work (not on v14 or v17). (It's very interesting that it works in that environment, though.)

Comment: Ok! Good to know. Do you know if there is a list of what stuff the Node REPL automatically imports?

Comment: @ruohola - I don't. I'm surprised not to find it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl). It looks like it's not a lot of things. `crypto`, as you said, is there, as is `constants`, `buffer`, `dns`, ... Use `node -p "Object.getOwnPropertyNames(globalThis)"` for a full list. **Really** interesting that the REPL auto-imports like that, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Yes, it has changed. **[`globalThis.crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/webcrypto.html#web-crypto-api) is globally available as of Node.js 19.**

Comment: And [`crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#crypto_1) is now one of Node.js's default globals, in their continuing attempts to support web APIs where possible.